# What is the spin angular momentum of eliptically polarized light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, quantum-spin, quantum-optics

Left circular light has angular momentum of $\hbar$ , right has angular momentum of $-\hbar$.

What is the spin of elliptical light, and how is conserved in processes ?
Is it the Poincare sphere that set the value of the angular momentum for the intermediate light polarization ?

Comment: Do you measure it on one photon, or do you average it over a large sample of photons?

Comment: Its a laser beam. But I guess should be for individual photons as two photon of LC and three photons of RC make RC.

Comment: Somebody will give you better and detailed answer, but it is basically a superposition of the two helicities. Just like elliptical polarization can be constructed from a horizontal and vertical polarization with different amplitudes and phases arranged right, you can mathematically transform it to a linear combination, i.e., superposition, of two circulars. Classically and also in Quantum theory

Comment: My question is easier is the angular momentum $\hbar cos(phi)sin(psi)$ for elliptical polarization or something similar as if it is on the poincare sphere. question

Answer (score 1):

Elliptical polarization can be written as a superposition of left- and right-circular polarizations. In Dirac notation (which works equally well in this case for classical optical fields):
$$ |\psi\rangle= \alpha |R\rangle + \beta |L\rangle , $$
where $|\alpha|$ and $|\beta|$ are complex coefficients such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$.

So from the angular momentum operator (for which $|R\rangle$ and $|L\rangle$) are the eigenstates, we get
$$ \langle\psi| L |\psi\rangle= (|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2) \hbar . $$
So we see that the angular momentum of an arbitrary elliptical polarization depends on the relative magnitudes of the combination of the two circular polarization states.

In terms of the Poincare sphere, one can associate the right- and left-circular polarizations with the north and south pole of the sphere, respectively. Then the distance from the pole, going from one to the other, would determine the amount of angular momentum.

The conservation of angular momentum is simply stating that the angular momentum would stay the same, regardless of what it is.